# Scala Reflection Conundrum: Can you explain these weird results?

Tags: scala, reflection

I wrote some Scala code, using reflection, that returns all vals in an object that are of a certain type. Below are three versions of this code. One of them works but is ugly. Two attempts to improve it don't work, in very different ways. Can you explain why?

First, the code:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime._
import scala.util.Try

trait ScopeBase[T] {
  // this version tries to generalize the type. The only difference
  // from the working version is [T] instead of [String]
  def enumerateBase[S: universe.TypeTag]: Seq[T] = {
    val mirror = currentMirror.reflect(this)
    universe.typeOf[S].decls.map {
      decl => Try(mirror.reflectField(decl.asMethod).get.asInstanceOf[T])
    }.filter(_.isSuccess).map(_.get).filter(_ != null).toSeq
  }
}

trait ScopeString extends ScopeBase[String] {
  // This version works but requires passing the val type
  // (String, in this example) explicitly. I don't want to
  // duplicate the code for different val types.
  def enumerate[S: universe.TypeTag]: Seq[String] = {
    val mirror = currentMirror.reflect(this)
    universe.typeOf[S].decls.map {
      decl => Try(mirror.reflectField(decl.asMethod).get.asInstanceOf[String])
    }.filter(_.isSuccess).map(_.get).filter(_ != null).toSeq
  }

  // This version tries to avoid passing the object's type
  // as the [S] type parameter. After all, the method is called
  // on the object itself; so why pass the type?
  def enumerateThis: Seq[String] = {
    val mirror = currentMirror.reflect(this)
    universe.typeOf[this.type].decls.map {
      decl => Try(mirror.reflectField(decl.asMethod).get.asInstanceOf[String])
    }.filter(_.isSuccess).map(_.get).filter(_ != null).toSeq
  }
}

// The working example
object Test1 extends ScopeString {
  val IntField: Int = 13
  val StringField: String = "test"
  lazy val fields = enumerate[Test1.type]
}

// This shows how the attempt to generalize the type doesn't work
object Test2 extends ScopeString {
  val IntField: Int = 13
  val StringField: String = "test"
  lazy val fields = enumerateBase[Test2.type]
}

// This shows how the attempt to drop the object's type doesn't work
object Test3 extends ScopeString {
  val IntField: Int = 13
  val StringField: String = "test"
  lazy val fields = enumerateThis
}

val test1 = Test1.fields // List(test)
val test2 = Test2.fields // List(13, test)
val test3 = Test3.fields // List()
```

The "enumerate" method does work. However, as you can see from the Test1 example, it requires passing the object's own type (Test1.type) as a parameter, which should not have been necessary. The "enumerateThis" method tries to avoid that but fails, producing an empty list. The "enumerateBase" method attempts to generalize the "enumerate" code by passing the val type as a parameter. But it fails, too, producing the list of all vals, not just those of a certain type.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Did you try decompiling the class files? That usually sheds some light on these kind of questions.

Comment: Yes, I did. The above is the bare-bones example. The original had the classes in different files and even packages.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem in your generic implementation is the loss of the type information of T. Also, don't use exceptions as your primary method of control logic (it's very slow!). Here's a working version of your base.

```
abstract class ScopeBase[T : universe.TypeTag, S <: ScopeBase[T, S] : universe.TypeTag : scala.reflect.ClassTag] {
  self: S =>

  def enumerateBase: Seq[T] = {
    val mirror = currentMirror.reflect(this)
    universe.typeOf[S].baseClasses.map(_.asType.toType).flatMap(
      _.decls
        .filter(_.typeSignature.resultType <:< universe.typeOf[T])
        .filter(_.isMethod)
        .map(_.asMethod)
        .filter(_.isAccessor)
        .map(decl => mirror.reflectMethod(decl).apply().asInstanceOf[T])
        .filter(_ != null)
    ).toSeq
  }
}

trait Inherit {
  val StringField2: String = "test2"
}

class Test1 extends ScopeBase[String, Test1] with Inherit {
  val IntField: Int = 13
  val StringField: String = "test"
  lazy val fields = enumerateBase
}

object Test extends App {
  println(new Test1().fields)
}
```

Comment: +1, good alternate solution that takes care of some issues, `Try` is pretty annoying to work with, and slow...

Comment: Many thanks, Nate! I did try to qualify T as universe.TypeTag, but that didn't work without the typeSignature comparison against universe.typeOf[T]. Thanks for pointing that out!

However, I'd rather parameterize ScopeBase with [T: universe.TypeTag]. Of course, the trait would have to become an abstract class, but that's fine.

Any way to get rid of [S], though?

Comment: @silverberry I've updated my answer to be an abstract class that also captures the sub-class's type information. I'm not sure how to make it work on an object directly, but you can do `class T extends ScopeBase[String, T]` and then `object T extends T`.

Comment: @silverberry One last edit here to capture strings from inherited classes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the type from `universe.typeOf` you can use the runtime class `currentMirror.classSymbol(getClass).toType`, below is an example that works:

```
def enumerateThis: Seq[String] = {
  val mirror = currentMirror.reflect(this)
  currentMirror.classSymbol(getClass).toType.decls.map {
    decl => Try(mirror.reflectField(decl.asMethod).get.asInstanceOf[String])
  }.filter(_.isSuccess).map(_.get).filter(_ != null).toSeq
}

//prints List(test)
```

Comment: Many thanks, Noah! That helps a lot. Now all my problems are solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

With everyone's help, here's the final version that works:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror, universe}

abstract class ScopeBase[T: universe.TypeTag] {
  lazy val enumerate: Seq[T] = {
    val mirror = currentMirror.reflect(this)
    currentMirror.classSymbol(getClass).baseClasses.map(_.asType.toType).flatMap {
      _.decls
        .filter(_.typeSignature.resultType <:< universe.typeOf[T])
        .filter(_.isMethod)
        .map(_.asMethod)
        .filterNot(_.isConstructor)
        .filter(_.paramLists.size == 0)
        .map(decl => mirror.reflectField(decl.asMethod).get.asInstanceOf[T])
        .filter(_ != null).toSeq
    }
  }
}

trait FieldScope extends ScopeBase[Field[_]]
trait DbFieldScope extends ScopeBase[DbField[_, _]] {
  // etc....
}
```

As you see from the last few lines, my use cases are limited to scope objects for specific field types. This is why I want to parameterize the scope container. If I wanted to enumerate the fields of multiple types in a single scope container, then I would have parameterized the enumerate method.